# PDO - Connect to multiply databases

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

So I know how to connect to a single database using PDO - see below code:

```
global $database, $social;
try {
    $dsn = "mysql:host=" . $database['host'] . ";dbname=" . $database['db'];
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $database['user'], $database['pass'], array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false));       
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // <== add this line
    //echo 'Connected to Database<br/>';

    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

The database settings for the first database is stored in `$database` - the second database information is stored in `$social`- My question is, how can I connect to both with the above code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll simply need to create another connection.

```
<?php 
global $database, $database2;
try {
    $dsn = "mysql:host=" . $database['host'] . ";dbname=" . $database['db'];
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $database['user'], $database['pass'], array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false));       
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
try {
    $dsn = "mysql:host=" . $database2['host'] . ";dbname=" . $database2['db'];
    $dbh2 = new PDO($dsn, $database2['user'], $database2['pass'], array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false));       
    $dbh2->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```